# Insering question marks('?') into the database rather than actual values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a registration form and I am using PHP bind parameters when inserting data into the database.

```
$fnameclean = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['first_name']); 
$passwordclean = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, hash("sha512", $_POST['password']));
$lnameclean = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['last_name']);
$emailclean= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_conn, $_POST['email']);



$stmt = $mysqli_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname, email, password) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $fnameclean, $lnameclean, $emailclean, $passwordclean);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

When I press the submit button, all I can see in my database are question marks in the fields: firstname, surname, email and password.

However, when I try to add information to the database without bind parameters it works perfectly fine

code:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname, email, password) VALUES ('$fnameclean', '$lnameclean', '$emailclean', '$passwordclean')";      
$mysqli_conn->query($query1);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `'?'` isn't a bind parameter, it's a string literal.

Comment: I found the mistake, it should be like VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) rather than VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

No `'` to be used in query where you use `?` for binding parameter. So your query should be like

```
$stmt = $mysqli_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```